# Deploying react on AWS ec2 using nginx

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, deployment, http-status-code-403

I'm deploying an react application on AWS ec2 instance. I use nginx as reverse proxy which set root as `/home/ec2-user/portfolio/PersonalWebsite/xyhsite/build`.
I receive a 403 forbidden error when visiting the page(the path is correct).

```
http {
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;

        root /home/ec2-user/portfolio/PersonalWebsite/xyhsite/build;
        index index.html index.htm;

    }
```

I google this issue and it seems that I need to give nginx permissions to access the directory(and it's parent folder). So I run following code:

```
sudo chmod -R +r /home/ec2-user/testIndex/TestIndex

sudo chmod +x /home
sudo chmod +x /home/ec2-user
sudo chmod +x /home/ec2-user/testIndex

sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /home/ec2-user/testIndex/TestIndex
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Now I can see the page but the css and js are missing. How to fix this problem.
This is my project build folder:
[project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeqMl.png)

Can some one tell me how to fix the problem of missing css and js files?
(I guess I need to allow permission for thoese directories but that a lot of work. And I have multiple projects to deploy on AWS. Is there a more convenient way to do this?)